# Is there an open-source web scraper for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, api, screen-scraping

I wish to gather some data from a licensed corporate intranet Stack Exchange, however it doesn't seem to expose the API as with public Stack Exchange sites. Are there any existing open-source libraries available for scraping data off a generic Stack Exchange site?

Comment: If by "internal" you mean one licensed to your company, then you should rather e-mail the team/support with that question. If by "internal" you mean Beta...then it is by design that it's not exposing the API (that's a guess of mine).

Comment: Edited to specify a company licensed implementation. I guess asking them to add an API is the best approach.

Comment: Is this a Stack Exchange 1.0 site? Indeed, the SE API only targets the public SE Network sites, and there is no mechanism for the API to target SE 1.0 databases (there are many fundamental differences).

Comment: Asked, and you're right, it's SE 1.0. Never mind, just an idea to work on in my spare time anyway.